# Custom file type with image field

Tags: 7, files

I've attached an image field to my custom file type to add additional information to my uploaded PDFs. The file field is attached to the node entity. But everytime I upload a PDF for my custom file type and add an image to it, Drupal overrides the filename and the filemime of the image with the ones of the PDF. Therefore I cant open the image anymore. I tried some things to reverse this but I had no success:

```
function mymodule_entity_presave($entity, $type) {
  if($type = 'file') {
    if(($entity->type == 'mytype') && ($entity->origname != $entity->filename)) {
      $entity = $entity->original;
    }
  }
}

function mymodule_file_presave($file) {
  if(($file->type == 'mytype') && ($file->origname != $file->filename)) {
    $file = $file->original;
  }
}
```

The file properties stay overridden. I even tried to load the file in hook_node_update(), change the properties manually and save the file again. But the file is destroyed then (file size just returns FALSE).

I would welcome every advise!

Many Thanks.
Daniel

Comment: what do you mean by 'custom file type'? a content type?  are you adding two fields (one for pdf one for image)? or trying to upload two files to one field? your question is unclear

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I use the file entity module. It allows to create my own (custom) file types, which are fieldable. I created a custom file type for pdf. Sometimes i need to add an additional image to these pdf, so i decided to add an image field to my pdf file type. Since i want to upload the pdf during a node creation, i added a single file field to the node. Now if i want to create a node, i upload the pdf. After uploading the file a new upload field appears for the image field of the file. But if i upload an image now and save the node then i get the behavior described above.

Comment: sounds like a bug - you may want to ask this in the issue queue for the module

Comment: Yes thats right. I think i will try it